# Gnome-do can't open folders on secondary partitions

Tags: gnome-do

I have  a problem with Gnome Do:
i have two partitions on my SSD, mounted by default.
Gnome Do fails to open folders in my data partition but not files.
Does anyone have any idea? I thought something about permissions, but if it was permissions it should not open files too.
I'm using Gnome 3.14.1
Thanks in advance.